# Early-Late Symbol Synchronizer on Non-Triangular Pulses

Tags: filters, digital-communications, digital-filters, dsp-core

I've been studying the basics of digital communications using the free book at [desktopsdr.com](https://www.desktopsdr.com/).

One of the examples is a 4-QAM demodulator which where symbol timing recovery is done with some Early-Late Gates after match-filtering with RCC.

[image]

I thought that Early-Late Gates were only useful when all pulses had triangular shape. However, binary data filtered with Raised Cosine does not:

[image: pic].

For non-triangular signals, the Early-late algorithm seems to output an error even when the sampling point is exactly right:

1. When there is a single symbol, I understand that the error L - E == 0
2. If there is a transition to a sequence of repeated symbols, however, I see that the estimated error is non-zero, which is wrong.

What am I missing?

[image: Early-Late Gate]

Comment: re: RRC != triangle: the symbols after the Matched Filter aren't *root* raised cosined, they're raised cosine formed; that doesn't really change your question, though :)

Comment: It might help when you think about your early and late delays to be spaced in a way that – if the signal was already synced – they would sample exactly in the middle between two symbols. Apply the second Nyquist criterion to that point!

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm still a little bit confused; for example, given the following [signal](https://imgur.com/a/ZKq6NVy); considering the early/late samples at exactly between symbols, I still don't see them at the same amplitude... the early one is at zero, and the late one is greater than zero. Re: RRC/RC, I will edit the question :)

Comment: Wouldn't that "false" error be undone when the repeated sequence is over and you get the downward transition?

Comment: Yes, it would. That’s a good point, thanks. It sounds like, for this case, Early-Late gates only provide useful error signals on symbol sequences like 010 and 101. Is that true?

Comment: I can't think of a reason the symbols would not be equally likely, so I believe (others please correct if wrong) that this sort of error is essentially averaged away over many symbols. Of course, if you have a constant signal, $x(t)=1$, you cannot sync to that but comms signals have repetition

Comment: @Engineer don't forget the squaring operation in front of the early/late detectors

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes good point, thank you. Also, I think usually the late and early samples are not spaced like that and they are more like $\frac{T_{sym}}{4}$ or something

Comment: @ManuelMenzella You're right that this kind of synchronizer works best with pulses that don't overlap in the time domain. However, it turns out that you can still use this idea with pulses that overlap, as long as the overlap is not too large. This is called "self noise" in many papers; see for example the original paper by Gardner where he suggests a large excess bandwidth, 70% or so IIRC. I've used Gardner with 35% excess bandwidth and it works well enough at moderate to large SNR.

Comment: Thanks again for all your responses - I now understand what self noise is, and proved myself it's not a big issue by [simulating](https://imgur.com/OuP2zcp) a few signals with deltaT of +/- 1/4 Ts. I can also see the accumulated error over a few symbols. However, I can't get this to work with a deltaT of +/- 1/2 Ts; see [simulation](https://imgur.com/cUvO2MJ). The derivatives on transitions are not present. From my original diagram above, it looks like the loop is locking half a symbol off the maximum effect point (see the delay of N/2 after the NCO strobe). Any ideas? @MBaz

Comment: Your signal (the top plot in your second simulation) does not look like a sum of pulses. What pulse shape are you using?

Comment: I should have made the title of each plot more clear. (1) is original digital signal, (2) is the same, but convolved twice with a square pulse, essentially making each pulse triangular, (3) is the rectification of the triangular pulses, (4) is the delayed signals in the previous plot, and (5) is the result of (late - early). (6) is the cumulative sum of (late - early) at the sample points. Essentially, I replaced the RC filter with a triangular convolution to make things easier to read. I am also rectifying the signal instead of squaring it for the same reason. @MBaz

Comment: If the pulse shape is triangular, why do you have long stretches where it's 1?

Comment: Ah - the triangular pulse has a width of 2 * Tsymbol. I believe this is equivalent to the main lobe of a RC pulse, which also has the same width. This is how you also get long stretches of ~1 when filtering with RC. Is this incorrect? If I’m wrong (and the pulse should be half the width), I don’t think it would have an effect on my question, right? The problem seems to be that rectifying the signal effectively doubles its frequency, causing the spacing of one full Tsymbol to result in one full waveform (of late-early), and therefore always have an error of zero. @MBaz